# urxvt, zsh agnoster font problem. symbols does not

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, urxvt

ON Fedora 31. All fonts properly installed. It works perfectly on gnome-shell but broken in i3-sensible-terminal ie urxvt

[image: The Terminal look like this]

All symbols are broken

[image: Gnome-Terminal works pretty well]

Since I am using i3 I want to stick to urxvt

The .Xdefaults is

```
URxvt.allow_bold: true
URxvt*font: xft:Monospace:pixelsize=14
URxvt*boldFont: xft:Monospace:bold:pixelsize=14
! Fix font space
URxvt*letterSpace: -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on URxvt. Installing fonts from the below link fixed the problem for me.

https://github.com/powerline/fonts

Installed the fonts and tested with the below command

urxvt -fn 'xft:DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline-10'

My .Xresources:

```
URxvt.font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline-9
URxvt.boldFont: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline-9
URxvt.italicFont: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline-9
URxvt.boldItalicfont: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline-9
URxvt.letterSpace: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Monospace doesn't support Powerline font, you can add a second font that can handle the characters the first can't handle:

```
URxvt.font: xft:Monospace:pixelsize=14,xft:Inconsolata\ for\ Powerline:pixelsize=14
```

You can replace `Inconsolata\ for\ Powerline` by any [powerline fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) you don't have that issue in gnome-shell you should have some installed